# Combinatorics under constraints

Tags: trees, combinatorics

I have two sets of points in space with known positions:

$$A = \{r_1^{\alpha}, r_2^{\alpha}, ..., r_n^{\alpha}\} \quad n \in \mathbb{N}, \quad r_i^{\alpha} \in \mathbb{R^3}$$

$$B = \{r_1^{\beta}, r_2^{\beta}, ..., r_m^{\beta}\} \quad m \in \mathbb{N}, \quad r_i^{\beta} \in \mathbb{R^3}$$

$$m < n$$

I want to pick $a$ points from $A$ and $b$ points from $B$ but I want to make sure that the distance between each points chosen is not lower than a given threshold $\lambda$.

If one want to knows the number of ways there are to pick $a$ points and $b$ points in both set simultaneously, this question can be answered by using basic combinatoric rules (Newton coefficients). But I am not sure how to mathematically translate the distance constraint.

I coded an algorithm that work ok for my specific problem, but I would like to know what kind of algorithm I could use to solve the general case of such problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "distance between each points chosen"?  Do you mean "distances between every pair of points"?  Do you mean "each point chosen has at least one other chosen point at distance $\ge \lambda$"?  Something else?

Comment: No point can be closer to any other point than $\lambda$, so yes every pair of points

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly, rather than answering in a comment.   Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, if $\mathsf{P} \neq \mathsf{NP}$, there is no efficient algorithm that solves your problem.

An algorithm that is able to solve your problem could be used to solve (the decision version of) the maximum independent set problem on unit disk graphs, which [is known to be $\mathsf{NP}$-hard](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X9090358O). This holds even in the special case in which points are in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $m=0$, $\lambda=1$, and we only want to know whether the number of feasible choices is $0$ or more than $0$.

Indeed, to decide whether there exists an independent set of size $k$ you can consider the set $A$ containing the locations of the graph's vertices and choose $a=k$. If there is at least one way to pick $a$ points from $A$ such that their distance is at least $1$, there there is an independent set of size at least $k$ in the unit disk graph.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you know any mathematical tools that can used to compute the number of possible combinations or at least estimate it?